HDMI working only with one monitor
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04, only one monitor works well in the HDMI port, I use another monitor some times, but when I connect the second monitor in the same HDMI port the screen on it starts to flash / blink. I suspect that it is due to not recognizing well the second monitor on the laptop because when I go to Settings / Displays it shows the same name for both monitors, this name belongs to the first monitor, and not to the second one. I tried deleting the "monitors.xml" file but it kept with the original name. Monitors are very different one is 32 inches, and other is 40 inches, both 1920*1080 resolution. Any ideas ?

Is the second monitor the exact same? Please edit the question and add the make and model of the 2 monitors and clarify the one with the issue.

They are different, edited the question, thanks

Are they computer monitors or TV being used as monitors? Are they made by the same company? If you disconnect the good one does the one with the issue still have the issue? You failed to add which one is acting up.

They are TV monitors, not by the same company, Yes the issue persist,
